# Why does passing a dataframe to list.extend() result in only column names stored in the list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I need lists of column names for several dataframes stored in a dictionary. It turns out that I accidentally got the desired result, but I thought that the code would work differently. Could someone explain why this code works?

Initial idea: loop through dictionary keys, add values (dataframes) to target lists --> get lists of dataframes --> [somehow] extract column names from dataframes.

What worked:  loop through dictionary keys, add values (dataframes) to target lists --> get lists of dataframes column names, nothing further required.

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

for key in dfDict.keys(): 
# each dfDict key has a value tuple of 3 dataframes --> key: (df1,df2,df3)
    list1.extend(dfDict[key][0]) # for df1
    list2.extend(dfDict[key][1]) # for df2
    list3.extend(dfDict[key][2]) # for df3
```

Expected:

```
list1 = [df1]
list2 = [df2]
list3 = [df3]
```

Actual:

```
list1 = [df1.columns]
list2 = [df2.columns]
list3 = [df3.columns]
```

It's awesome, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.extend` iterates over its argument, and `DataFrame.__iter__` iterates over the dataframe's column names. There is not much more to it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['a', 'b'])    
print([col_name for col_name in df])
```

Outputs

```
['a', 'b']
```

This is somewhat analogues to `dict.__iter__` iterating over the keys.

```
df[col] for col in df
```

behaves "the same" as

```
dict[key] for key in dict
```

---

Either way in your use case you should use `append` (and as shown above, you don't have to explicitly use `.keys`)

```
for key in dfDict:
    list1.append(dfDict[key][0])
    list2.append(dfDict[key][1])
    list3.append(dfDict[key][2])
```